# Deploying SARIMA - Python

Tags: python, time-series, forecast

I have a few questions on forecasting with SARIMA as I am getting mixed answers:

1. Do I need to make my data stationary - my dataset exhibits both, trend and seasonality (spikes every two weeks)?
2. If I am to deploy my time series SARIMA model, what are the caveats of getting SARIMA into production? I read somewhere that it cannot be automated, but I don't understand why, providing that we perform the grid search every time we run the model.
3. The dataset is rather interesting i.e. the trend and seasonality patterns appeared starting from December 2018. But it also means that if I split the data from December 2018 till now into training & test dataset, there won't be enough datapoints. Are there any dataset size recommendations when running SARIMA or it is general that there should be at least N number of seasonal cycles?
4. As my forecast is to be run on a weekly basis, I assume that what I need to do in regards to the workflow: run a job at the end of the week: gather the new records for the past week > do an N data transformation > split into training & test > run the grid search of the best parameters > train the model > test the model > do forecast for the next 7 days. What am I missing?